# org.apache.lucene.analysis plugins missing in eclipse 4.7.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

org.apache.lucene.analysis plugins missing in Eclipse 4.7.2. If anyone knows
 any Alternate Option, Please suggest me.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340563

Comment: You  can always just include the jars in your plugin.

Comment: I am searching, But I didn't find for eclipse 4.7.2.

Comment: I am saying that you can include plain jar files which are not plugins as part of your plugin. Since they are just ordinary jars they don't have to be 'for Eclipse 4.7'.